# AccessDeniedException Spring Security Can Not Catched By AbstractRequestCycleListener wicket

Tags: spring-security, wicket

I have custom class from `AbstractRequestCycleListener`:

```
package com.rudiwijaya.rcommerce.security;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.wicket.Session;
import org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider;
import org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler;
import org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.RedirectPolicy;
import org.apache.wicket.request.IRequestHandler;
import org.apache.wicket.request.Url;
import org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.AbstractRequestCycleListener;
import org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;

import com.google.common.base.Throwables;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import com.rudiwijaya.rcommerce.WicketSession;
import com.rudiwijaya.rcommerce.pages.AccessDeniedPage;

public class NotAuthorizedRequestCycleListener extends AbstractRequestCycleListener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotAuthorizedRequestCycleListener.class);

    @Override
    public IRequestHandler onException(RequestCycle cycle, Exception ex) {
        // Since our actual exception is wrapped, we need to find based on the chain
        final List<Throwable> chain = Throwables.getCausalChain(ex);
        final AccessDeniedException notAuthorizedException = Iterables.getFirst(
                Iterables.filter(chain, AccessDeniedException.class), null);
        if (notAuthorizedException != null) {
            final Url url = cycle.getRequest().getClientUrl();
            log.debug("Got exception " + notAuthorizedException.getClass().getName() + " on " + url, ex);
            final WicketSession wSession = (WicketSession) Session.get();
            wSession.error("Anda tidak memilik akses.");
            wSession.dirty();
            return new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(AccessDeniedPage.class), RedirectPolicy.NEVER_REDIRECT);
        } else {
            return super.onException(cycle, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

In `init()` method from `AuthenticatedWebApplication`, I added:

```
getRequestCycleListeners().add(new NotAuthorizedRequestCycleListener());
```

How can I to catch the `AccessDeniedException` spring security in wicket's `AbstractRequestCycleListener`?

My point is showing custom access denied page with keep the url, in Wicket command like:

```
return new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(AccessDeniedPage.class), RedirectPolicy.NEVER_REDIRECT);
```

Comment: I think this is enough to check access denied `getApplicationSettings().setAccessDeniedPage(AccessDeniedPage.class);`

Comment: @soorapadman... I think so, but I want to keep the url with ```AccessDeniedPage```.. Thank you @soorapadman

Comment: I didn't get what url with ? Do you mean like this `http:://www.abc.com/accessdenied`?

Comment: In wicket.. I have a class page with mount ```/admin``` --> ```http:://www.abc.com/admin``` with spring security configuration like: 
```.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole(SecurityRole.SYSADMIN.name(), SecurityRole.ADMIN.name()).and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)```. If logged in user without the roles access ```/admin```, AccessDeniedPage shows up with url ```http:://www.abc.com/accessdenied```. I want ```http:://www.abc.com/admin``` with access denied content (AccessDeniedPage.class)

Comment: Btw, I want to try your suggestion: ```getApplicationSettings().setAccessDeniedPage(AccessDeniedPag‌​e.class);```.. I hope it is works..

It is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Most probably Spring Security filter is executed before WicketFilter, so Wicket doesn't have a chance to do anything.

You may need custom AuthenticationEntryPoint to handle such failures via Spring Security APIs.

Comment: Maybe.. I am gonna check the filters in web.xml... Thank you @martin-g